# Extending the Radius Protocol

Tags: protocols, radius

I intend to use radius protocol to send some values from client to server.I am using vendor-specific value pairs and I have defined types  as well.
However,value length for vendor-specific data is 255 but my data length is crossing it. 
can any one please tell me how to incorporate data longer than 255 bytes?

Comment: ya sure ur right definately will dot it

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

You should use RFC 6929 [Extended-Vendor-Specific-5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6929#section-4.5) or [Extended-Vendor-Specific-6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6929#section-4.6), Both which allow you to specify a 'more' flag, to indicate the attribute is broken across several attributes.

This allows RADIUS servers to automatically reassemble the complete value, and guarantees that the value fragments are not re-ordered by proxies.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a UDP packet, and so long as you don't intend to work with a common RADIUS server out there, you can certainly define a new message value.   For example, I could define a new base message type where the number of octets value is now in octet multiples, for example, 16 bytes.

In this case, the new message type may have an octet size of 230.   This is no longer 230 bytes, but 230*8 = 1840 bytes.

The only problem is when a standard RADIUS server sees it.